# How to get two array by where?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of emails.
I need to get two arrays using my `where` expressions.

```
var firstArray = emailTo.Where(e => whiteList.Contains(e.Address));
var secondArray = emailTo.Where(e => !whiteList.Contains(e.Address));
```

How to do this?

P.S. While I was writing, I have understood how to do this:

```
emailTo.ForEach(e => ... use if construction and add to array ... );
```

Maybe you have any solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `ForEach` method instead of a simple `foreach` loop?

Comment: @JonSkeet Congratulations to 600 000 points!

Comment: @Default: Thanks. Just another 400K to go to get the million ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var twoArrays = emailTo.GroupBy(e => whiteList.Contains(e.Address),
                                (key,g) => g.ToArray())
                       .ToList();

var firstArray = twoArrays[0];
var secondArray = twoArrays[1];
```

**NOTE**: the `firstArray` and `secondArray` above may not be the exact `firstArray` and `secondArray` in your code. That's because the order of arrays can't be determined. To make sure, you may want to append `OrderBy(g=>g.Key)` after `GroupBy`, then `Select` it like this:

```
var twoArrays = emailTo.GroupBy(e => whiteList.Contains(e.Address))
                       .OrderBy(g=>g.Key).Select(g=>g.ToArray())
                       .ToList();   
//Now the firstArray is always at the index 1
var firstArray = twoArrays[1];
var secondArray = twoArrays[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx):

```
var firstArray = emailTo.Where(e => whiteList.Contains(e.Address)).ToArray();
var secondArray = emailTo.Where(e => !whiteList.Contains(e.Address)).ToArray();
```

Side-Note_ instead of `List.ForEach` which is a .NET 2.0 method to loop a list i would use a simple `foreach`. Then you don't need to create another collection.

```
foreach(var emailTo in firstArray)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstArray = emailTo.Where(e => whiteList.Contains(e.Address)).ToArray();
var secondArray = emailTo.Except(firstArray).ToArray();
```

Comment: thought the same answer but King King answer is more accurate and efficient I believe